# MySQL LEFT JOIN With a GROUP BY and aggregate operators chokes

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables in MySQL:  ALUMNI and CALLRES .

The ALUMNI table has AlumID as its primary key.  It has 14483 recs.

The CALLRES table has CallKey as its Primary Key and it has a field AlumID
that is indexed.  (It is a foreign key for ALUMNI, but no formal constraint designating that.)  CALLRES has about 18000 recs.

The following query works fine. (0.2 seconds, 14461 result rows)

```
 SELECT    ALUMNI.AlumID, MAX(CALLRES.CallTime), COUNT(CALLRES.Outcome)
 FROM      ALUMNI JOIN CALLRES ON (ALUMNI.AlumID = CALLRES.AlumID)
 GROUP BY  ALUMNI.AlumID
```

However, this is missing listing the ALUMNI that have no CALLRES records.
(There aren't many: 14483 - 14461 = 22 are being missed at the moment.)

I want to get them in the list, so I want a LEFT JOIN instead of a JOIN.  I guess the added records will have NULL in the aggregate columns.

Is this allowed?

When I change the query by just changing "JOIN" to "LEFT JOIN", I do not get an error, but the query sits indefinitely.  So:

```
 SELECT    ALUMNI.AlumID, MAX(CALLRES.CallTime), COUNT(CALLRES.Outcome)
 FROM      ALUMNI LEFT JOIN CALLRES ON (ALUMNI.AlumID = CALLRES.AlumID)
 GROUP BY  ALUMNI.AlumID
```

takes "forever".  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the missing list, you can do:

```
SELECT ALUMNI.AlumID
FROM   ALUMNI LEFT JOIN CALLRES ON (ALUMNI.AlumID = CALLRES.AlumID)
WHERE  CALLRES.AlumID IS NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT ALUMNI.AlumID FROM ALUMNI
WHERE ALUMNI.AlumID NOT IN (SELECT AlumID FROM CALLRES)
```

I think the first SQL is better.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I think you are correct and these can solve my problem.  But I am hoping someone will explain what is wrong, if anything, with my approach.  I'm curious as to why my LEFT JOIN query is strangling MySQL ... especially since it breezes through the natural JOIN query.